# ASP MVC Edit Post Function has null Parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to create a very basic MVC app based on a tutorial.  I am using the default routing, and simple Views and Model.

The problem I am having is with the HttpPost Edit function.  I am expecting an object of my "MyObject" type to be passed as the parameter, but it always comes back null.

Here are my Edit functions from the controller (the Get function works properly):

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (!id.HasValue)
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    var item = (from obj in mDB.MyDatabaseObjects
                where obj.Id == id
                select obj).First();
    return View(item);
}

//
// POST: /Main/Edit/5

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MyDatabaseObject someObject)
{
    var original = (from obj in mDB.MyDatabaseObjects
                    where obj.Id == someObject.Id
                    select obj).First();

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(original);

    mDB.ApplyCurrentValues(original.EntityKey.EntitySetName, someObject);
    mDB.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Note that my (nearly identical) Create method works as expected:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude="Id")] MyDatabaseObject newObject)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View();

    int max = mDB.MyDatabaseObjects.Max(data => data.TaskOrder);

    newObject.TaskOrder = max + 1;
    mDB.AddToMyDatabaseObjects(newObject);
    mDB.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Thanks,
wTs

Answer (score 2):

Ensure the values on your view for MyDatabaseObject are inside of the form. Validate these values are being posted over - inspect Request.Form or use change the method signature to use

```
FormsCollection collection
```

simply to validate the values are getting posted. If its choosing that method - it should be matching the properties to the form field - its generally very simple.

Comment: Thanks @Adam.  The collection was being returned as expected, just not as the Type expected (see my Answer)

Comment: Note - deleted my answer, as it turned out not to work as expected either.  I don't understand why Create and Delete Posts both work, returning the correct object.

Comment: send me your sample project - I'll get it to work : )   adam.tuliper at gmail

Comment: Wish I could, but its semi-proprietary, and I'm the New Guy here.  :)

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that ModelState.Values is returning a single value, instead of values for all my properties.  However, if I make the parameter a FormsCollection, I correctly (or at least apparently correctly) get values for all properties.

Comment: can you put a sample together that fails? Also does your model that is defined on the view contain these other properties? are there any attributes to exclude binding for them?

Comment: thats fine.. about to leave for some DINNER++ woohoo! its friday!

Comment: +1 for dinner.  Well, for your comment about dinner.  I probably won't actually join you for dinner...(sorry, it's been a long week)